# Journey Builder - Loop contact within Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a scenario in my Email Journey where I need to loop continuously for a period (variable period based on a date field on Lead) until a criteria is met.

Doing some research I found that Journey Builder doesn't allow looping within a Journey. As a work around I can allow re-entry to the journey and evaluate the criteria again and again till the criteria is met.

There are 2 steps in the Journey, the first step is an email that is sent out to everyone once while the second step is the loop in question.

The problem I am facing is if I allow re-entry, it sends the first email multiple times. Does Journey builder have use the concept of Measures that is available in Automation studio so that I can build rules around emails based on Send Analytics.

Are there alternatives to how we can loop to ensure the contact doesn't exit the Journey till a criteria is satisfied ?

Comment: Could you set a value on the Subscriber (ex. Email_Sent = True) add a Decision Split before the Email to check that value. If Email_Sent == True use a Join to bypass the Email?

Comment: regarding 'ensure the contact doesn't exit the Journey till a criteria is satisfied' I would suggest you create a Goal in your Journey with your exit criteria and in the final Summary step (of configuring the Goal), enable the exit option: 'When the customer reaches this Goal, they will exit the Interaction.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by you, Journey builder will not allow looping within a journey. As a work around, in the same process you are trying with multiple re-entry, you can set a parameter to True after the Email is sent first time and add a split activity before email send to check if the same parameter is true. If its true, move directly to the next step skipping Email send.

By this way even if the contact enters the journey multiple times, it will recieve the entry email only once and will be taken trhough the rest of the journey once the criteria its met.

Comment: I haven't been able to come up with another way of resolving this. Parameter check along with multiple re-entry works as expected.